# What is the time complexity of Java's ArrayList.sublist(startIndex, endIndex) method?

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity, sublist, constant-time

The question basically says it all. Suppose I have a (sorted) list that can contain anywhere from 1K to 1M items. I have a `starting index` and an `ending index`. If I use the `ArrayList.sublist(start, end)` method, is the time complexity O(n) or O(1)? I did check for answers here since I'd think would be a common question, but although I found a duplicate answer for a LinkedList, I couldn't find a specific question about ArrayList. Thanks to all for their answers!

Comment: @IlyaBursov No. There is no copy step. See the Javadoc. The time complexity is *O(1)*.

Comment: @EJP you're right, I've completely forgot about that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The sub-list is backed by the source list. There is no copy step, so the time complexity is *O(1)*.

Comment: Thanks! I did check the javadoc, but I wanted to be 100% certain.